# Proving the existence of a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there exists a linear map $T: C^2 \to C^3$ such that $T(1,i)=(-i,0,3+i)$ and $T(2,0)=(4,4,2-i).$ What is $T(5-i,5+i)?$

Attempt:

I know that in order for a linear map to exist, we must have a basis such that for any $v_i\in C^2$, $T(v_i)=w_i\in C^3$.

What bases should I choose?
Well, I suppose I can choose $(1,i),(2,0)$ for $C^2$.

Indeed, $(1,i),(2,0)$ is a basis for $C^2$ since for any $a,b \in F$ the only solution to $0=a(1,i)+b(2,0)$ is the trivial one.

I am still lost here and do not know how to proceed...

As of 1.54am PST Sep 22 I have a solution, I will update later.

So, with the help from the community, I was able to do the following:

I wrote $(5-i,5+i)$ as a linear combination using the basis above. The coefficients being $a=(1-5i)$ and $b=(2+2i)$.

Then, define $T$

$T(x,y)=T(a(1,i)+b(2,0))$.

It then follows that $T(5-i,5+i)=(3+7i,8+8i,14-12i)$.

Comment: The question essentially asks you to show that $(1, i)$ and $(2, 0)$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $$T(1, 0) = \frac{1}{2} T(2, 0) = (2, 2, 1 - \frac{1}{2}i)$$ and $$T(0, i) = T(1, i) - T(1, 0) = T(1, i) - (2, 2, 1 - \frac{1}{2}i) = ...$$

So try defining a transformation $\tilde{T}$ by

$$\tilde{T}(x, y) = x \tilde{T}(1, 0) + y \tilde{T}(0, 1) = ...$$ and making sure that it agrees with the data you're given.

Answer (score 2):

First hint is to show that {(1,i),(2,0)} is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then what you want to do is extend $T$ linearly to all of $\mathbb{C}^2$ (Every vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$ can be written as a linear combination $a(1,i)+b(2,0)$). Then define $T$ as $$T(a(1,i)+b(2,0)) = aT(1,i)+bT(2,0).$$ By construction T is linear.